# VueJS not using environment variables

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, axios, environment-variables

I want to use my API called `visitor_api` from my vue project `master_admin`. Both are running in a production environment using docker.

---

My setup:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  visitor_api: # api backend
    container_name: visitor_api
    image: misterX/server-backend:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env_api
    networks:
      - visitor-network
    ports:
      - 6001:3000

  master_admin:
    container_name: master_admin
    image: misterX/master-admin:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env_frontend
    networks:
      - visitor-network
    ports:
      - 4099:80

networks:
  visitor-network:
    driver: bridge
```

.env_frontend

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://visitor_api:3000
```

master_admin service

```
const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

---

If I want to access my `master_admin` frontend the console output says this:

```
xhr.js:178 GET http://192.168.192.3:4099/modules 404 (Not Found)
```

So I can access the frontend but the connection to the API obviously doesn't work, because the frontend tries to access itself but not the API. This should mean that the enviroment variables are not set.

But running `docker inspect master_admin` shows that the variables are set:
[image]

Comment: I think they're set in the runtime environment, and not when Vue CLI is building the app. env variables are replaced during build, so make sure those variables are set during build.

Comment: @TimVN yes this was the problem, thank you